# How to strip the white space or left justify the string scraped through BeautifulSoup? str.strip() or str.ljust() doesn't work

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

How to strip or left justify the white space from the data scraped using BeautifulSoup?
The data is converted to str from unicode.

tried str.strip() and str.ljust(), str.replace("\n","").checking each character against None and displaying if not None is also does not work

```
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  import requests    
  with open('f.html') as f:
    soup=BeautifulSoup(f,'lxml')
    article = soup.findAll('div',class_='modal-content')
    for i in article:
        print (str(i.text).strip())
```

Output got:

```
reset to default listTour

                            Start here for a quick overview of the site





                    Help Center

                        Detailed answers to any questions you might have
```

expected output:

```
 reset to default listTour
 Start here for a quick overview of the site
 Help Center
 Detailed answers to any questions you might have
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't pretty, but I think this will work.

```
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  import requests    
  with open('f.html') as f:
    soup=BeautifulSoup(f,'lxml')
    article = soup.findAll('div',class_='modal-content')
    for i in article:
        text=str(i.text)
        text=text.split('\n')
        text=[x.strip() for x in text if x.strip()!='']
        output=''
        for t in text:
            output+=t+'\n'
        print(output)
```